# AspectJ around Mule MessageReceiver

Tags: aspectj, mule, spring-aop

I'm looking to wrap an aspect around a Mule Flow, IE I'd like to define an `@Around` that would be triggered when something enters a Mule flow, so that I can perform my own statistics gathering. I haven't found an easy "Flow" class to wrap around, but I have seen that `MessageReceiver` is a good class, or at least the implementations of this class.

However I'm not an expert in AspectJ and I'm unable to get this to work. I have my `@Aspect` class with a method that looks like this.

```
@Around("execution(public * org.mule.api.transport.MessageReceiver+.*(..))")
public Object addMonitor(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Before");
    Object object = pjp.proceed();
    System.out.println("After");
    return object;
}
```

but I cannot get the Before/After strings to print out when methods in `HttpMessageReceiver` are called. I have set a debug point in my flow and can see that `org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(MuleMessage message)` is being called, which is an implementation of `MessageReceiver` but I'm never seeing the call to my Aspect.

Is it possible to perform this kind of Aspect in Mule?

//EDIT: As said, I'm new to AspectJ and AOP, so I'll say that I am using spring in Mule to handle my `@Aspect` class. I have examples of this working on Spring-handled beans, but not on regular POJO's that are not managed by spring. My Spring configuration looks like:

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</spring:beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed load-time-weaving, so I had to add `-javaagent` for aspectjweaver and spring-instrument, and add an `META-INF/aop.xml` which linked to my `@Aspect` class, but as soon as I did that, I was allowed to do `@Around("call(* org.mule.api.transport.MessageReceiver.routeMessage(org.mule.api.MuleMessage))")` to get the calls for Mule.

Comment: It would be useful to see your aop.xml content and the -javaagent full line for those who try to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yes Nicholas would really appreciate if the full details were available here. I'm trying to get something similar working both from Studio and standalone with limited results.